# How to enable correct user recognition by the smart contract withdraw?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

With this smart contract, users can deposit ether and withdraw ether. The contract should store each user and the deposit made, allowing the amount to be withdrawn at any time. Within the code there are no errors, but unfortunately the function with which the withdrawal is made does not work properly, in fact the ethers remain within the contract and are not returned to the owner.

```
   contract vaultCoin {
        uint amount; 
        address user;
        uint amountDeposit;
    
        function vaultCoin() public {
            dev = msg.sender;                    
        }
    
        address public dev;                          
        address[] public users;                   
        uint[] public totalDeposited;                
    
        mapping(address => uint) balances;
        
        function sendToken() public payable {
            balances[msg.sender] = amount;
            require(msg.value > 0.001 ether); 
            
            user = msg.sender;               
            amountDeposit = msg.value;      
            
            users.push(user);                     
            totalDeposited.push(amountDeposit);     
        }
    
        function getUsers() public view returns (address[]) {    
            return users;
        }
    
        function getAmount() public view returns (uint[]) {
            return totalDeposited;
        }
    
        function retireMyCoins() public payable {
            require(msg.sender == user);
            require(msg.value == amountDeposit);
            balances[msg.sender] = 0; 
            msg.sender.transfer(balances[msg.sender]); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
balances[msg.sender] = 0;
```

Your code sets the balance to 0 at first

```
msg.sender.transfer(balances[msg.sender]);
```

And then transfers the already zeroed-out value to the user.

---

Solution:

1. Record the balance in a memory variable
2. Zero out the storage value
3. Transfer the value from the memory variable

```
uint256 balance = balances[msg.sender];
balances[msg.sender] = 0; 
msg.sender.transfer(balance);
```

This intermediate step prevents [reentrancy](https://swcregistry.io/docs/SWC-107) attack.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately it doesn't work, none of the users are able to withdraw the deposited funds. Also it seems that with the withdrawal function set up this way the smart contract withdraws other ether exactly as with the sendToken function. I am new to Solidity and am probably doing something wrong that invalidates my smart contract.

Comment: @Alex Now I see that you're also incorrectly setting the balance in the `sendToken()` function... You need to assign `balances[msg.sender] = msg.value;` - a global variable that reflects the amount sent with the transaction. Your original approach `balances[msg.sender] = amount;` effectively sets zero value, as that's the default value of the `amount` storage property.

Comment: Thank you very much Petr. I don't know why but none of the users are able to withdraw their coins, they can only deposit them and by calling the withdraw function nothing is withdrawn. I would like to bring back the updated code with your advice here but it is not possible to post it in the comments.

Comment: Thank you very much bro. I cleaned up my code which now works thanks to your suggestions. I then created a store variable 'uint256 balance = balances[msg.sender];' at the beginning of my contract. Then inside the store function I inserted 'balances[msg.sender] = msg.value;' which saves the value inside the variable for each transfer. Finally I concluded by inserting the function 'withdraw' which allows each user to withdraw their balance.